# warning hash() unknown hashing algorithm sha256 when try to access admin in magento 2.3.0

Tags: admin-panel

[image]Getting error / warning when trying to access admin owing to unknown hashing algorithm sha256

Comment: Check your PHP version.
in command line run php -v command

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/How-to-solve-Unknown-hashing-algorithm-sha256-in-Magento-2-3/m-p/117407#M7801

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1)Open localhost/phpmyadmin or 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin which certainly gives you an error.

2).To fix this, restart server to start the service of PHPMYADMIN.

3).if you are on local server, open your xampp or wampp, stop all services then start it.

4).This will fix your all issues for sure